# WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it

Tags: java, xml, append, nodes

I have created a method which takes three paremeters of types Node, Document and String respectively. The method creates an Element type and appends it to the node.

```
public Node populateProcessNodeRecursively (Node node, Document doc, String name){
    if (name.equals("WFD.Stencils.WF_START")){
        Element startEventNode = createNewNodeElement (doc, "bpmn2:startEvent");
        startEventNode.setAttribute("id", arrayOfNodesIds.get(ind));
        node.appendChild(startEventNode);
    }
    return node;
}
```

where the implementation of `createNewNodeElement` method is:

```
public static Element createNewNodeElement (Document doc, String tagName){
    Element theNodeElement = doc.createElement(tagName);
    return theNodeElement;
}
```

But I get the following exception :

> Exception in thread "main" `org.w3c.dom.DOMException`: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.

exactly when i try to append the newly created element to the node.

I have solved the same problem when I tried to append to my document an element from another
 existing document using importNode but I don't know how to fix this problem because i am in the same document, i am not retrieving nodes from another doc

Comment: What language is this? Java?

Comment: yes Java, sorry i forgot to mention it